# alignment issue with sidewaystable enviroment in LaTeX

Tags: tables, tabulary, sidewaystable

I am having an alignment issue with the entries that I am entering in my table. I use `inform3` class and the output looks like [image]

Here are two important things: i) when I use `.` in any of the entry, it messes up the entire table as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D75fW.jpg). ii) When I use math mode, it changes the numbers. For instance, if I use `$67.1$`, it shows me 80 for some reason.

```
\begin{sidewaystable}  
\vspace*{20\baselineskip}
\setcellgapes{0pt}  
\makegapedcells       
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}   
\sisetup{group-four-digits}  
  \centering
  \caption{My Table}
  \small                     
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l  
                                *{2}{S[table-format=5.0]}  
                                *{16}{S[table-format=6.0]} } 
     \toprule[\heavyrulewidth] 
       &        & \multicolumn{4}{l}{{[}1{]}}    & \multicolumn{4}{l}{{[}2{]}}           & \multicolumn{4}{l}{{[}3{]}}         & \multicolumn{4}{l}{{[}4{]}}     \\
    \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth](lr){3-6}   \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth](lr){7-10} \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth](lr){11-14} \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{15-18}   % <--- changed
$\mathbf{|V|}$ & $\mathbf{|m|}$ & \textbf{Status} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Time\\ (sec)\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Gap\\ ($\%$)\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}BB\\ Nodes\end{tabular}} & \textbf{Status} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Time\\ (sec)\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Gap\\ ($\%$)\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}BB\\ Nodes\end{tabular}} & \textbf{Status} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Time\\ (sec)\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Gap\\ ($\%$)\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}BB\\ Nodes\end{tabular}} & \textbf{Status} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Time\\ (sec)\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Gap\\ ($\%$)\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}BB\\ Nodes\end{tabular}} \\
    \midrule
500  & 10  & {status1}  & 67.1   & 0.00  & 9639     & {status1}     & 25.3  & 0.00  & 2301  & {status2} & 66.9   & 0.00 & 1335     & {status2}     & 201.3  & 0.00 & 1479  \\
    \bottomrule     
    \end{tabular*}  
  \label{table1}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

Comment: What exactly is the alignment issue?

Comment: The entry in the ```Gap``` column is not centered. Also, I believe, it is probably related to using ```.``` in the entry. Here how my table looks when I enter three rows https://imgur.com/LG19Soe

Comment: The issue is due to the table-format option you used. Make sure that it fits the contents of the respective columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Please always provide MWE (Minimal Working Example, a small complete document, which we can compile as it is and which reproduce your problem).
- From one row of table we can't know, if numbers in the other rows are bigger as they are in showed row.
- Please show image of table in question, link can become dead after while.
- From provided code can be concluded, that table consist (after first two columns)  four groups of data, from which in the first column are text, other three have numbers with different number of integer and decimal digits. This should be reflected in table's columns specification (see MWE below).
- For column header you can use `makecell` macro from the package with the same name. Using it the code will become much shorter and clearer.

```
\documentclass{article}% i still haven't inform3 document class
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{mathtools}                      % new
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert} % new
\usepackage{bm}                             % new


\begin{document}
    \begin{sidewaystable}
%\vspace*{20\baselineskip}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\sisetup{group-four-digits}
\renewcommand{\cellset}{\bfseries\linespread{0.84}\selectfont}
\renewcommand\cellalign{bc}
  \centering
  \caption{My Table}
  \small
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} 
                        *{2}{S[table-format=3.0]}
                        *{4}{l S[table-format=2.1] S[table-format=1.2] S[table-format=4.0]}
                                }
     \toprule
    &   & \multicolumn{4}{c}{[1]}   & \multicolumn{4}{c}{[2]}           
        & \multicolumn{4}{c}{[3]}   & \multicolumn{4}{c}{[4]}   \\
    \cmidrule(l){3-6}\cmidrule(l){7-10}\cmidrule(l){11-14}\cmidrule(l){15-18}
{$\bf\abs{V}$} 
    & {$\bf\abs{m}$}            & \makecell{Status}         & {\makecell{Time\\ (sec)}} 
    & {\makecell{Gap\\ ($\%$)}} & {\makecell{BB\\ Nodes}}   & {\makecell{Status}} 
    & {\makecell{Time\\ (sec)}} & {\makecell{Gap\\ ($\%$)}} & {\makecell{BB\\ Nodes}} 
    & {\makecell{Status}}       & {\makecell{Time\\ (sec)}} & {\makecell{Gap\\ ($\%$)}} 
    & {\makecell{BB\\ Nodes}}   & {\makecell{Status}}       & {\makecell{Time\\ (sec)}} 
    & {\makecell{Gap\\ ($\%$)}} & {\makecell{BB\\ Nodes}}       \\
    \midrule
500 & 10  
    & status1   & 67.1  & 0.00  & 9639     
    & status1   & 25.3  & 0.00  & 2301  
    & status2   & 66.9  & 0.00  & 1335     
    & status2   & 201.3 & 0.00  & 1479  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
  \label{table1}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I use ```l```, it left aligns all the entries. How can I make it right aligned?

Comment: @ball_jan, use `r`. I like to encourage you to read some introductory text about writing tables. For example https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables